# How to signal a new row using delimiters in a text file that will be imported in excel after

Tags: excel, csv, import, vba

for the following text format from a text file:

> Name: Test1,Email: Test1@email.com,Phone: 81273807,Age: 22,Gender:
>   Male,Name: Test2,Email: Test2@email.com,Phone: 81453807,Age:
>   32,Gender: Female..... etc

Id like to import in excel so that it looks like this:

```
> Name  |    Email        |  Phone   |  Age |  Gender |
> Test1 | Test1@email.com | 81273807 |  22  |  Male   | 
> Test2 | Test2@email.com | 81453807 |  32  |  Female | 
> etc
```

is there anyway to do this by formatting the text file in a certain way ? can VBA be avoided ?

Comment: using the import function of excel, but i am open to any solution

Comment: You can try Find/Replace `,Name: ` with `,[New Line]Name: `

Comment: i am really inexperience with VBA

Comment: No problem - just find/replace `,Name:` with a new line before `Name:` and it brings it over correctly

Comment: Then you can use Text to Columns (in the Data tab), with a comma delimiter, to separate everything without VBA.  That should help get you started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Open a new blank workbook.
- Click the Sheet1 name tab and choose **View Code**.
- When the VBE opens, paste the following into the code sheet titled *Sheet1 (Code)*.

> Code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Parent.UsedRange.Cells.Count = 1 And _
       Target.Cells.Count = 1 And _
       Target.Address(0, 0) = "A1" Then
        On Error GoTo safe_exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim a As Long, b As Long, arr1 As Variant, arr2 As Variant, hdr As Variant, tmp As Variant
        arr1 = Split(Replace(Target.Value2, ",Name:", vbLf & "Name:"), vbLf)
        For a = LBound(arr1) To UBound(arr1)
            arr2 = Split(arr1(a), Chr(44))
            For b = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)
                tmp = Split(arr2(b), Chr(58))
                hdr = Application.Match(tmp(0), Rows(1), 0)
                If IsError(hdr) Then
                    Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1) = tmp(0)
                    hdr = Application.Match(tmp(0), Rows(1), 0)
                End If
                Cells(2 + a, hdr) = tmp(1)
            Next b
        Next a
        Columns(1).EntireColumn.Delete
    End If

safe_exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

- Tap Ctrl+Q to return to your new, blank worksheet.
 - Open the TXT file in notepad or some other text editor and copy the whole thing.
 - Go back to your new, blank Sheet1 and paste the text into A1.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comments, you can replace `,Name:` with `\nName:` (new line/carriage return).

This is very easy to do in Notepad++ (a free program)

https://notepad-plus-plus.org/

Make sure you set the `Search Mode` to `Extended`

Use Find: `,Name:`

Replace With: `\nName:`

[image: Demo]

It comes over looking like this when you set it to `Delimited` using `Comma`

[image: Demo2]